# Decompose complex vector by SU(4)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

This question is about to decompose (or reduce dimension) complex vector by $SU\left( 4 \right)$.
Given any $4\times1$ complex vector $B$. We can build  $a_i$,and matrix$\lambda_i,i=1\ldots n $, $a_i \in\mathbb{R}$,$\lambda_i$  $\in$ one of the basis of generating matrices of $SU\left( 4 \right)$,  make
$$e^{ja_i\lambda_1}\times e^{ja_2\lambda_2} \times\ldots\times e^{ja_n\lambda_n}\times B= \left[ \begin{matrix} C \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{matrix} \right] $$where $C$ is a complex.

Question is:

1. The maximum value of $n$? (Maybe 6 I think, but I don't know why)
2. How to select such $a_i,\lambda_i$?
3. Where can I find the references to solve this problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one $A_i$, where the first row is just $B^\dagger$ while the other three are row vectors orthogonal to $B$.

Comment: Thanks, darks. But I want to get the maximum value of n.

Comment: @Mark.Connor why should this number be limited? You can add an infinite number of $A^\dagger A$...

Comment: @mark Why do you think it's $6$?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @draks. As for independent matrix, I want to express that $A_i$ is something like generator. $SU\left( 4 \right)$ has 15 generators, so the maximum value of $n$ should be less than or equal to 15. $B$ 's degree of freedom is 8, $C$ 's degree of freedom is 2. That's why my guess is 6.

Comment: @mark then you have to specify the generators explicitely!

Comment: Thanks for your comments @draks. It should be specified at the beginning. Now it was revised.